# User interface for an OpenGL project?

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, visual-c++

I am working on an OpenGL project for a solar system using Visual C++. I am done with quite a bit of the coding, but I need to implement it as a user learning module, which includes an overview button, a stop button and an info button. I want to make it like a form, with a panel containing the buttons and the a panel for viewing the animation. I tried using GLUI but it's not very useful for my implementation. Is it possible to create a form in Visual Studio, and import this code in the panel function?

Comment: GLUI is 7 years old. Have you *tried* creating a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using QT for the GUI portions of your project ? You can create a panel for QT buttons and GUIs. You could use the `QGLWidget`  for your panel to view the animation.

A good tutorial for using Qt Creator with Opengl (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18).

There are also many good examples of the OpenGL + QT + Visual studio in the "C:\QtInstallPath\examples\opengl" directory.

If you wanted didn't want to use QT you could use C++\CLI to assist with the GUI portions of the code. The following link shows how to create an OpenGL view on a windows form in managed C++. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16051/Creating-an-OpenGL-view-on-a-Windows-Form.

Comment: Is it possible to just create a form directly in Visual C++ and embed my solar system code on the panel click ?